# jQuery $.when Firing Immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

I'm trying to batch together AJAX calls together to get an event when they have all completed:

```
this.xhrs.push($.ajax({ type: "POST", url: this.options.firstUrl, data: this.options.data, datatype: 'json' }));
this.xhrs.push($.ajax({ type: "POST", url: this.options.secondUrl, data: this.options.data, datatype: 'json' }));
this.xhrs.push($.ajax({ type: "POST", url: this.options.thirdUrl, data: this.options.data, datatype: 'json' }));
this.xhrs.push($.ajax({ type: "POST", url: this.options.fourthUrl, data: this.options.data, datatype: 'json' }));

$.when
    .call($, this.xhrs)
    .done(function(first, second, third, fourth) {
        ...[process data]...

        this.loading.hide();
        this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds);
        this.map.setZoom(this.map.getZoom() - 1);
    }.bind(this));
```

But the function is called immediately, I've also tried .then instead of .done but that fires immediately as well.

It's definitely not that the AJAX calls are returning too quickly to notice, as one of them takes 20 seconds to return data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `$.when.apply()` instead of `$.when.call()`

---

Excerpt from [`Function.prototype.call()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

> ... fundamental difference is that `call()` accepts an argument list, while `apply()` accepts a single array of arguments.

---

In your case you are passing in an array and the array itself is not a promise so using `call()` will cause `$.when` to resolve immediately.

Using `apply()` will spread all of the promises within the array into individual arguments ... each of which  must resolve before the `$.when` will be resolved

---

Since `Promise` API is now supported in all modern browsers you could also just do:

```
Promise.all(this.xhrs).then(function(allResults){...`
```

Comment: Ah, rookie mistake. I can't believe I actually Googled it beforehand to make sure I was using the right one, my speed reading clearly needs work.